# Property file naming convention

Tags: java, properties

We have to add properties of multi-level hierarchy companies. 
We are unable to find a suitable name for those properties.
Please suggest the property name:

```
company.level1
company.level.one
company.heirarchy.one
company.heirarchy1
```

or any other suggestions are welcome

Update: We used: company.heirarchy.one

Answer (score 0):

Usual standard is dots for hierarchy levels, hyphens for multiple worded properties eg

company.level-one

Digits or names of numbers is probably a matter of preference. I find names clearer.